# Disabling colliders for a specified amount of time in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to programming and Unity so please have patience. I am trying to disable a collider for a specified amount of time upon pressing a button (In this case, the button "s"). I have been trying to do this by using the "WaitForSeconds" command but I have never used it before and I don't know it works, but I tried anyway and as I expected it didn't work. I have to mention that the simulation does run with no errors but when I press "s" the collider doesn't disable at all. As I have mentioned I am very new to programming and Unity so I apologize if I don't understand some solutions you may suggest. Anyways here is the code

```
{
    public bool IsFacingR = true;
    public bool IsFacingL = false;
    public Rigidbody2D RB;
    public BoxCollider2D m_col;
    
    void Update()

    {
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            
            IsFacingR = true;
            IsFacingL = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            
            IsFacingR = false;
            IsFacingL = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            Slider();
            
            StartCoroutine(SlideCol());
            m_col.enabled = false;
            
            
        }
        
    }

    

    void Slider()
    {

        if (IsFacingR == true) 
        {
            RB.AddForce(Vector2.right * 9999f);
            
               
            
        }
        if (IsFacingL == true) 
        {
            RB.AddForce(-Vector2.right * 9999f);
            
                
            
        }
    }
    IEnumerator SlideCol()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        m_col.enabled = true;


    }
}
```

Comment: Throw in debug messages. See where it gets to

Comment: Ok so I have added debug messages(2 if the m_col is enabled or not and 1 on the waitforseconds command) and they all responded positively and the waitforseconds one and the enabling the collider after 1 second responded at the specified time as they were supposed to. So the problem must be that the collider doesn't disable for some reason even though the debug console says that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i tried your code in my project and it works fine. I can see collider disable for one second. Maybe there is someting that makes your collider always enable.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. I realized it must be because I have another script on the gameobject that keeps the collider on at all times. I will work on it a little and see what I can do to fix it.